# Import and export links from WordPress.com to private site

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, links, import, export

Is there some way to export/import links from a wordpress.com site to a private site? I have a rather large directory of links. I fetch the opml file and the category levels are there, but when I use the Bloggroller importer, it doesn't create the categories? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going from WP to WP, then you want to use the built-in exporter and importer. Your links should come along with it. I'm not sure about the categories with it, but this might help http://ellejohara.com/blog/making-the-wordpress-opml-tool-slightly-more-useful/

Comment: Nope. The categories doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I just did some research, and unfortunately, the export import is just pages/posts in an RSS XML/format.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/download-view-schema-or-dtd-for-xml-import

Answer (score 0):

when you say a private site, what platform is it? export file would essentially be the same, but how the new platform imports and handles the data is on their site, not WordPress.

Comment: Sorry, the private site is a WordPress site